# Is there way to generate block or create styling like a block inside a block in Moodle?

Tags: php, html, css, block, moodle

I want to create few blocks inside a parent block in Moodle.s there a way to create block instance manually???

OR

Modify block content as it look like a block by adding some html etc..

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to create a moodle block which displays some details of enrolled courses. So i am trying to create master block and create child block which containg course information.. So i want to add child block in to the 'content' area of the parent block... Is there way to do that???

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no support in Moodle for nested blocks. On the other hand, it would probably make no sense to have it, since the "block" is a well defined stand-alone entity, embedding some very simple logic.

What you may want to do is to create a new block and to use the functions from `weblib.php` to create the graphic elements that you need within it. If you need something more complicated, you will probably need a "module" (in Moodle terms).